# sed: Delete multiple lines from files between pattern, when found string

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to delete lines between two pattern (Beginn: info / End: } ), where match a string.

Here my file:

```
# bla bla
# bla bla
# bla bla
# bla bla

nnssjnds nkjdnds "nsrnsnmks" ffsns {
  is on or off at 9:12:43 23/02/2015;
  is nass or trocken at 08:32:12 22/02/2015;
}

info text01text {
  beginn 30/04/2015 10:00:04;
  end    30/04/2015 19:00:04;
  check1 30/04/2015 11:30:04;
  check2 30/04/2015 13:00:04;
  check3 30/04/2015 16:00:04;
  Check4 30/04/2015 18:00:04;
  build top end;
  mix water 0102030456789;
  xim "43ndf392rfhf<DF>3}";
  test space = "ALLFINE";
  eman cpre "ann";
}
info text02text {
  beginn 30/04/2015 10:00:04;
  end    30/04/2015 19:00:04;
  check1 30/04/2015 11:30:04;
  check2 30/04/2015 13:00:04;
  check3 30/04/2015 16:00:04;
  Check4 30/04/2015 18:00:04;
  build top end;
  mix water 0202030456789;
  xim "43ndf392rfhf<DF>3";
  test space2 = "ALLFINE2";
  eman cpre2 "ann2";
}
info text03text {
  beginn 30/04/2015 10:00:04;
  end    30/04/2015 19:00:04;
  check1 30/04/2015 11:30:04;
  check2 30/04/2015 13:00:04;
  check3 30/04/2015 16:00:04;
  Check4 30/04/2015 18:00:04;
  build top end;
  mix water 0302030456789;
  xim "43ndf392rfhf<DF>3";
  test space3 = "ALLFINE3";
  eman cpre3 "ann3";
}
```

my sed script

```
:point
/^info/,/^}/ {
   /}/!{
      $!{
         N;
         bpoint
      }
   }
   /0202030456789/d;
}
```

My sed script worked correct with the string `0202030456789` and delete all lines from info `text02text {` to `}`.
Try it with the string `0102030456789` from `text01text`, then delete `sed` to `}` from line "  xim "43ndf392rfhf3}";" and the lines

```
test space = "ALLFINE";
eman cpre "ann";
}
```

don't delete.

How is it possible to delete all lines, where found the string?

Thanks!

Comment: replace `/}/!{` by `/^ *}/!{`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### From your sample

try this:

```
:point
/^info/,/^}/ {
   /\n *}/!{
      $!{
         N;
         bpoint
      }
   }
   /0202030456789/d;
}
```

#### But I prefer:

```
/^info .*{/ {
  :a;
    N;
    /\n *}/!ba;
    /0202030456789/d;
}
```

This could by written (under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)):

```
mixToDel=0302030456789
sed < file '/^info .*{/{ :a;N;/\n *}/!ba;/'$mixToDel'/d;}'
```

Or maybe:

```
sed < file '/^info .*{/{ :a;N;$!{/\n *}/!ba};/'$mixToDel'/d;}'
```

to prevent missing `}` at end of file:

```
/^info .*{/{
  :a;
    N;
    $!{
        /\n *}/!ba
    };
    /'$mixToDel'/d;
}
```